# creating a .Mat file from images' database (in octave)

Tags: octave

i've been taking Andrew Ng's lecture on Machine learning and i wanted to know how to construct ".mat" files(like the "ex3_data1.mat" file in the lecture) from images' database...i've 20x20binary images of different objects ..how do i save them in a .mat file along with the output class/label?i'm trying to implement this on Octave so any help would be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: What did you try? Did you understand the class?

Comment: yes i understood the class but nowhere is it mentioned how those pixels and their corresponding 'y' values were assigned....i've constructed an image database of 4 folders each with certain number of 20x20 binary images ....and that's as far as i could reach...i've no idea as to how to proceed...

Comment: As your question is labeled, you will not get any help except from people who are taking the same class and knowing what you are talking about. You have to express your question so that people who are not taking the class can give you some advice. I am not an octave guy by the way. I just wanted to draw your attention.

Comment: thanks..i'll try and edit them and explain in detail